# What's in the correlation matrix of a power set?

Tags: boolean-algebra, correlation, neural-networks

Consider the power set $P(\Omega)$ of a finite set $\Omega=\{0,\dots,N-1\}$, $|P(\Omega)|=2^N$.

Consider the [Ackermann-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIT_predicate) characteristic encodings $\{s^{(i)}_k\}$ of the subsets $S^{(i)}\in P(\Omega)$, i.e. sequences of length $N$ with $s^{(i)}_k = 1$ if $k \in S^{(i)}$ and $s^{(i)}_k = -1$ if $k \not\in S^{(i)}$.

Let the Hebb correlation between two subsets $S^{(i)}, S^{(j)} \in P(\Omega)$ be the number

$$\omega_{ij} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k\in\Omega}s^{(i)}_k s^{(j)}_k$$

Note that this is nothing but the symmetric weight between two neurons in a [Hopfield network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network) of $2^N$ neurons that was trained with the above encodings of the $N$ numbers $n \in \Omega$ by the [Hebb rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network#Hebbian_learning_rule_for_Hopfield_networks).

**Edit:** This is how the 256x256 matrix $\{\omega_{ij}\}$ for $N=8$ looks like when $S^{(i)}$ is the subset $S\in P(\Omega)$ with Ackermann encoding $i$ and when only the entries with $\omega_{ij}\neq 0$ are painted black, depicting the pairs of subsets that are "correlated". *[Note that this square can be bent to a torus with two copies of the diamond in the middle on it - and some more regularities.]*

[image]

> I wonder what can be read off the matrix $\{\omega_{ij}\}$ concerning
>   the structure of $P(\Omega)$. Could I - for example - tell whether
>   $S^{(i)} \cap  S^{(j)} = \emptyset$, knowing only the complete matrix but not the sets $S^{(i)}, S^{(j)}$? Or the number of elements of a set $S^{(i)}$?

What is easy to read off:  $S^{(i)} = \overline{  S^{(j)}}$ iff $\omega_{ij}=-1$.

What obviously cannot be read off: the specific elements a set $S^{(i)}$ consists of. This information is lost.

**Edit**:
It is easier to consider the matrix

$$ \alpha_{ij} = |S^{(i)}\triangle S^{(j)}|$$

with $S^{(i)} = \overline{  S^{(j)}}$ iff $\alpha_{ij}=N$.

**Edit**:
You may want to compare the correlation matrix above with the intersection matrix where the pairs of subsets with an empty intersection are depicted black.

[image]

Comment: Note that for each subset $S$, the automorphism $P(\Omega) \to P(\Omega)$ which takes $T$ to $S \triangle T$, the symmetric difference between $S$ and $T$, leaves your matrix essentially unchanged. So you cannot find information that this automorphism does not preserve. Edit: in particular, the answers to both questions in your box is "no".

Comment: Because there are $2^N$ such automorphisms there seems a lot of information to get lost. How can this information be characterized (I have no clue)? And which information remains (in the positive)?

Comment: @Mees: Do you think this is OK: I can tell - up to complement - which $S^{(i)}$ is the empty (or full set) and from this - up to complement - which  $S^{(j)}$s have 1, 2, .., N/2 elements. And that's it?

Comment: that seems wrong, unless I misunderstand something. About a single $S^{(i)}$ you cannot say anything, because an automorphism of the form given above can take it to any other subset. You can only say something about pairs (or triples, or...) of subsets of $\Omega$. For example, given two subsets $S^{(i)},S^{(j)}$ you can identify $|S^{(i)} \triangle S^{(j)}|$.

Comment: I guess I understand now. So it would be necessary (and sufficient) to "mark" one set - e.g. $S^{(0)}$ - as the empty set, which cannot be done "structurally"? From this, the above analysis would work - but would be trivial.

Comment: Once you do that, you can determine how many elements are in each subset, but you still cannot determine which ones they are. Any automorphism of $\Omega$ itself also gives an automorphism $P(\Omega) \to P(\Omega)$.

Comment: That's for sure.